# Disable mobile view bootstrap with a link (without php)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I disable the mobile view on a mobile device with a link such as "Desktop View".

But it should not changed it once, but also when the user clicks on any futur link on this page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example, http://jsbin.com/fizesigo/1 , I used jquery-cookie plugin to save variable for enable or disable mobile so you can switch between responsive and non-responsive classes. I used the example from official non-responsive sample http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/ , you can modify css easily

Comment: Not bad, but I guess you forget the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` part. Is it also possible to toggle it, so there are not two links?